# using query in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I want to get a list of player names that have a certain rank value associated with them from a given table. So, please return me the player names that have a rank higher than 1.5 .

Here's the table:

```
    A      B
    1.5    Marko
    3.2    Suzy
    1.0    Stevie
    1.2    Choch
    2.0    Mango
```

What is a good way to do this?

I know about INDEX and MATCH, FILTER, and QUERY... and have tried all those, but can't get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: So =filter(A1:B5, A1:A5>1.5) for example does not work for you? Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The equation used is:

```
=filter(B1:B5, A1:A5 > 1.5)
```

[image]